# How to add nobomb in vimrc

Tags: vim, config

I want to set nobomb in my vimrc config but it wont work. Other commands work but this one doesn't. It works when I use the command in the window with the file opened but not in the config.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option local to the buffer. It is set by Vim (once upon file read) if the file on disk has the BOM. Same for file encoding, file format, last EoL presence and such. You get what you had.